# Is it possible to apply quick charge 3.0 to USB-C?

Tags: usb-c, usb-host

There's a wall outlet with a USB-A fast charging port

It has a USB-A charging port that supports 9V 1.67A fast charging.

It uses FP6601Q and supports QC2.0/QC3.0.

[image]
I'm trying to change the USB-A charging port to a USB-C charging port, but it doesn't work well.

Can we simply switch A to C port to support 9V 1.67A charging speed without USB-PD negotiations?

Below is a circuit that I made simple. I simply changed the port and connected only pull-up resistance to the cc pin of the usb-c port.
[image]

However, it initially charges 9V 1.67A, but after a few minutes, the charging speed drops to 5V 1.67A

I tried all 56k/22k/10k resistance with cc pull up resistance, but the result was the same.

What should I do?

Comment: Without negotiation, how would the PD know what your desired voltage level is? USB D-/D+ are important for this reason. You saw the results on what happens without proper negotiations, the voltage dropped to a "default" state. Use the USB spec as guidance on making a proper solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Even if I connect pull-up resistance to cc pin and charge 9v using fp6601q ic, does it drop to 5v if there is no additional pd negotiation?

Comment: What kind of device are you trying to charge with your modification?

Comment: Devices with 15w charging support are targeted.
It's a general-purpose 15w fast-charger supported quick charge\

Comment: From where does the 5V for the CC pull-ups come from? Directly from VBUS? Also, an USB Type-C receptacle is not allowed to have VBUS being supplied until a connection to device is detected. So that is not USB compliant and will damage something if you accidentally plug in a wrong cable between two devices you did not intend to.

Comment: I took the line separately from Vbus and made a 5V output separately through a regulator such as mic5205_5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not the way you are approaching it

You'll need QC-to-USB PD translation. You can do this by interfacing a QC downstream (powered device) chip with a PD upstream chip (power source) using a small microcontroller. Translator "widgets" may also exist on the market, I didn't check.

Some USB power testers offer this translation. I know that the Fnirsi FNB58 I got does it: you can plug it into a QC charger, select the translation option, and it will appear to other devices like it was a USB-C PD charger with higher voltages available.

Comment: The reason I tried to do this is because of the USB Type-c conversion gender.
Simply plug in a c-type conversion gender in the USB-a charging port and charge my phone using the C to C cable, I confirmed that 9V 1.67A fast charging is supported stably.
So I thought it would be good to take out the USB-A and insert the USB-C reatacle.